# How to Register user via fingerprint in xamarin form?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I want to make Xamarin form application, which registers user fingerprint (from device's fingerprint scanner) and stores, next time user put his fingerprint scanner, he should be authenticated from the fingerprints stored in device.

Comment: You do not have access to the actual built-in fingerprint sensor and its data, it is abstracted and accessed via the OS's APIs so you can ask the OS to authenticate a user that is using your app. Android now uses the BiometricPrompt (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.html) and iOS uses theirs LocalAuthentication API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication?language=objc)

Comment: Xamarin does have some docs that also cover this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/touchid#Adding_Touch_ID_to_your_application & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fingerprint-authentication/

Comment: Hey,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

As SushiHangover said . You do not have access to register fingerprint in your app.But if you want to  authenticated from the fingerprints stored in device.You can use the package from nuget which called [Plugin.Fingerprint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Fingerprint/).

**Usage:**

> iOS

Add **NSFaceIDUsageDescription** to your Info.plist to describe the reason your app uses Face ID. Otherwise the App will crash when you start a Face ID authentication on iOS 11.3+.

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need your face to unlock secrets!</string>
```

> Android

Request the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

The first line is for the standard Android API and the second for Samsung devices using the Pass API.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
```

> Forms

```
var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync("Prove you have fingers!");
if (result.Authenticated)
{
  // Authenticate success
}
else
{
 // Authenticate fail
}
```

I have uploaded my sample on [github](https://github.com/luczha/FingerPrintDemo),you can download it for test.